# Autocomplete doesn't take the true value

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

it doesnt take the value which is coming from list (with autocomplete), it just takes the value which i write into the textbox. I would be happy if someone gives me any trick.

Thanks in advance,

[image]

```
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
    "Mustafa Basyurt",
    "Hakan Öz",
    "Ahmet Taşkın",
    "Burhan Top"
    ];

    $("#<%=txtMembers.ClientID%>").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        messages: {
            noResults: '',
            results: function () { }
        },
        select: function () {

            $("#members").append("<span class='button blue' id='" + ItemNo + "' style='font-size: 16px; margin-left:0px'>" + $("#<%=txtMembers.ClientID%>").val() + "<a onclick='RemoveItem(this);'><img src='../../Style/images/icons/close.png' style='vertical-align:central; margin-top:2px' /></a> </span> ");


        }

    });



});
```

HTML:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMembers" runat="server" Width="90%" BackColor="LightBlue" Height="20px"></asp:TextBox>

<div id="members"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Your select handler should be something like (provided ItemNo has some value) :

```
select: function (event,ui) {
            $("#members").append("<span class='button blue' id='" + ItemNo + "' style='font-size: 16px; margin-left:0px'>" + ui.item.value + "<a onclick='RemoveItem(this);'><img src='../../Style/images/icons/close.png' style='vertical-align:central; margin-top:2px' /></a> </span> ");   

        }
```